# Can't delete WordPress cookies

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, setcookie, multisite

I am working on WordPress multisite, and I have changed the login functionality. However, it needs the users to delete old cookies before using this functionality I have created. So I am trying to clear the user's cookies by setting a new cookie, `custom_wordpress_login_cookie`, to know which of the users have old cookies in the browser, as shown in the following code.

```
add_action('init', 'clear_all_cookies_before_login');
function clear_all_cookies_before_login(){
    if( ! isset( $_COOKIE['custom_wordpress_login_cookie'] ) ){
        foreach( $_COOKIE as $key => $value ){
            setcookie( $key, '', time() - YEAR_IN_SECONDS);
        }
        setcookie( 'custom_wordpress_login_cookie', 'true',
            time() + YEAR_IN_SECONDS, '/', COOKIE_DOMAIN, false, true );
    }
}
```

The new cookie is being set, but the old cookies persist. What could be the issue?

Comment: So I work on wordpress multisite. the cookie domain constant refers to the main domain. but I want to remove cookies for the subdomain. we have to place $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST"]. as domain argument while deleting the cookie. It solved the issue.
`setcookie( $key, '', time() - YEAR_IN_SECONDS, '/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
`
Thanks for everyone. I appreciate your answers.

Comment: changing the Salt keys would have solved the issue on Multisite as well :)

Comment: I tried. It didn't clear the cookies.

Comment: It is not deleting the cookies. It's just invalidating the values stored in them. So the user will end up having to login again.

Comment: I got your point, but it didn't work. I have also came up with other simple solution. That is, to define COOKIEHASH constant with a custom value. This will make the server to neglect all the old login cookies.

Comment: @CornelRaiu the issue is the user will stuck at login page if the old login cookie persist no matter what its value is. So I have to delete it.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent creation of a second cookie with the same name, pass `/` as the path argument to [`setcookie()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

And so, you must change this line:

```
setcookie( $key, '', time() - YEAR_IN_SECONDS);
```

to:

```
setcookie( $key, '', time() - YEAR_IN_SECONDS, '/');
```

Also note that the way you're expiring cookies may not work if the user's system time is configured incorrectly. This is rare*, but does happen. A simpler way to expire cookies is to simply call:

```
setcookie( $key, '', 1, '/');
```

*the user would likely run into TLS issues if the webpage is served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer related to how you can clear cookies, but this solution will help you make sure that all the users currently logged into your website will need to login again.

Go in the wp-config.php and reset the secret salt keys. You can generate new ones here: https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ .

That way it will force all of your users to login again and you no longer need to write code to delete the users' cookies.

Comment: will this delete all the old session cookies ? it would solve my issue.

Comment: Yes. This invalidates all the standard WP cookies. This is a good article to understand more: https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/wordpress-salts/

Answer (score 1):

Try: `setcookie( $key, '', time() - 3600, '/', COOKIE_DOMAIN);`

Comment: I did. It is not working.

Comment: So I work on wordpress multisite. the cookie domain constant refers to the main domain. but I want to remove cookies for the subdomain. we have to replace COOKIE_DOMAIN with $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST"]. I solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

According WordPress documentation, it combines the salt keys with the password. The hash function mixes these up and gives a result. After that it stores inside a cookie to "remember" the login process or tracking behavior.

example: That's the reason two **different** usernames with the **same** password are successfully identified as different logins.

First you have to make distinct cookies for every user. Let's say ***custom_wordpress_login_cookie*** will contain inside a string with the username or any associated encoded string (preferred).

Then you will check if the ***custom_wordpress_login_cookie*** exists and contains the appropriate username.

Act accordingly, if found, perform your logic and then delete (unset) the cookie. Else create a new one.

The following code explains the flow...

```
function clear_all_cookies_before_login() { 
// Current Time of visit
$time_now = date('F j, Y g:i a');
 
// Check a cookie already set
if(isset($_COOKIE['custom_wordpress_login_cookie'])) {
 
// Found Cookie 
function check_visitor() {
 
// Retrieve information to use for your logic 
$lastvisit = $_COOKIE['custom_wordpress_login_cookie'];
$string .= 'Since your last login '. $lastvisit .'. We have a tone of new things!'; 
 
// Delete the old cookie so that we can set it again with updated time
unset($_COOKIE['custom_wordpress_login_cookie']); 
 
return $string;
}} else { 

// Not found cookie
function check_visitor() { 
$string .= 'Welcome to our website! Please login...' ;
return $string;
}   
}
add_shortcode('New_Message', 'check_visitor');
 
// Set new cookie with expiration of 1 Day
setcookie('custom_wordpress_login_cookie',  $time_now , time()+86400);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must used first **unset**

```
unset( $_COOKIE[$v_username] );
setcookie( $v_username, '', time() - ( 15 * 60 ) );
```

Once that’s done, we will force the cookie to expire by setting its value variable to a null value (“”) and passing in a timestamp that’s in the past (time() - ( 15 * 60 )).

Answer (score 0):

You are doing absolutely correct but the deletion of the cookie would not work. The above code will only expire the cookie in the current session. You have to destroy the session also if you want to make the old cookie dis-appear. Thus your new code would be like this:

```
add_action('init', 'clear_all_cookies_before_login');
    function clear_all_cookies_before_login(){
        if( ! isset( $_COOKIE['custom_wordpress_login_cookie'] ) ){
            foreach( $_COOKIE as $key => $value ){
                setcookie( $key, '', time() - YEAR_IN_SECONDS);
            }
            setcookie( 'custom_wordpress_login_cookie', 'true', time() + YEAR_IN_SECONDS, '/', COOKIE_DOMAIN, false, true );

            //Destroy the session and re-direct the user to other location
            //this will make sure to disappear the old cookie and new cookie 
            //only will remain

            session_destroy();
            header("Location:/");
        }
    }
```